# Android design approch clarification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am working on an android application.I have to make my application compatible for all the device.I know two ways to this. That are

1. Create separete layouts for devices and tabs.for example
   layout-small,layout-normal,large, etc and
   layout-sw600dp,layout-sw360dp and layout-sw720dp
2. Use one layout and use different drawble resourse like
   drawble-ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi for device and drawable-large-mdpi and
   xlarge-mdpi for tablet.

Which way is better. Please give me a reply with some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your layout Design structure and orientation is same for all screens then it is always best to use single layout. I hope you have already read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html). But if your layout structure is different then there is no other way.

Even if you can use single drawable resources for multiple screen then I think it is bets to use the sigle resource folder. Say for some images it will not do any harm for you if android automatically resize to the screen size ( like full screen image or images where stressing is not a problem). In those cases you can use those images in xhdpi folder only

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In each category device I may have some differences..like textview textsize etc.Then How can I keep single layout ?

Comment: If the changes are minor then you can do it from code. but if there are lots of changes then create different layouts

Answer (score 1):

These both are completely different approaches.

- Different layout files should be used only if you want to make different views for different screen sizes. If your core view stays same, there is no sense in making separate layout files.
- If your view stays the same and there is only change in resource files, it would be smarter to make separate drawable folder for devices you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is the best otherwise if you need to make changes in layout you will have to change it in multiple files. Also you might have to use different styles for various device configurations. 
Even if you use first option, you will have to keep separate images in drawble resourse like drawble-ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi. 
Use one layout and keep multiple drawables and styles to support all device configurations.